# how long on average would it take for a person to randomly step on any point $n$ times.

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

how long on average would it take for a person to randomly step on any point $n$ times.

This person walks in a random way every odd step: he can choose to go north or south $1$ meter.

Every even step, he walks 1 meter east or west.

My question is, on average, how many steps will it take to go to any point $n $ times?

I would like to learn how to solve problems like this. I'm a 9th grader hoping to learn probability.

Answer (score 0):

Your walk is essentially two independent random walks, so let's just consider one of them, i.e. a (symmetric) random walk on the integers.

You are asking about the expected time of the $n$th visit to any arbitrary point. Let's first try to answer the problem, but with the point being the starting point.

It turns out that you can show that such a walk is recurrent (the probability of return is 1), but *not positive-recurrent* (the expected (1st) return time is infinite).

You can learn more by consulting these lecture notes which i found nice [http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rrw1/markov/M.pdf](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Errw1/markov/M.pdf)

Comment: This analysis fixes the return point, which didn't seem (at least to me) initially intended by the question.

Comment: It won't matter, if my answer is "infinite" in either case, right? To be fair, the question could have been more precise.

Comment: what's the expected amount of times it hits any point n times does this help? @BenjaminWang

Comment: It will matter though.  For example, in the 1D symmetric random walk, if every square has a counter that ticks up when you step on it and you ask how many steps are needed, on average, for **some** square's counter to show a "2", it won't be infinite.  It'll basically be a geometric rv.

Comment: Okay, so given that point P. Then you can just repeat my analysis, pretending that P is the starting point. So, I still think the answer is "infinite" for the point P. (Since P is arbitrary, we can say the same for all points)

Comment: @Brian Moehring okay, I see that it is more complicated. Would you like to answer the question instead? It's midnight here and i will leave it here

Comment: I changed the question a little bit to see if it makes more sense cause I don't care which point as long as a point has been hit n times for any point to be hit twice can cause it to happen north east south west which should happen 1/16 the time so it can't be infinity?

Comment: It's not what he's asking he's asking when any point witch if random should happen some times